# WHS 2011, how to extend existing 2nd sub tab?

Tags: windows-server

In the SDK, there is a sample on [how to extend an existing tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg514001.aspx). If I deploy this sample in the "Server Folders and Hard Drives" tab, this custom extension will be applied to the "Server Folders" only.

How do I extend the second tab, "Hard Drives"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, darn it. [It's a limitation by design](https://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsHomeServer/feedback/details/641628/cant-extend-2nd-sub-tab-in-whs-2011-sdk).